# Split integer into parts using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have an input field and the user may type time in different format(800,08:00,08:00 am etc).I need to display what ever the user input into a time format(xx:xx am/pm).

Example:

```
1.'800'=>'08:00';
2.'1245'=>'12:45';
3.'1000 am'=>'10:00 am';
4.'10.00 am'=>'10:00 am';
5.'9 am'=>'09:00 am';
```

So I could type in "800" and it would convert it to "8:00" or I could type in "2145" and it would convert it to "21:45".

I have tried with `str.split(/[:;,. \/]/);` ,but this is applicable only in the case of example 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to parse the string into its components:

```
var myregexp = /^(\d{1,2}?)\D?(\d{2})?\b\s*([ap]m)?$/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    hours = match[1];
    minutes = match[2];
    ampm = match[3];
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Start of string
(         # Capture into group 1:
 \d{1,2}? # one or two digits, preferably one
)         # End of group 1
\D?       # Match an optional non-digit
(         # Capture into group 2:
 \d{2}    # Exactly two digits
)?        # End of (optional) group 2
\b        # End of number
\s*       # Optional whitespace
(         # Capture into group 3:
 [ap]m    # am or pm
)?        # End of (optional) group 3
$         # End of string
```

You can then use the results to construct a new, normalized string, which in this case means

- adding a zero if the hours part is single-digit
- adding `00` if the minutes part is `undefined`
- deciding what to do if the `am`/`pm` part is `undefined`.

A regex can't do this part of the exercise since a regex can only match text that is present in the original string, not add to it dynamically.

Comment: @TimPietzcker not working properly in the case of '9 am'.How will you change the regEx ?

Comment: @SujathanR: That wasn't part of the spec. What else isn't?

Comment: @TimPietzcker that's now in the spec,can you help me ?

Comment: @TimPietzcker what about if the input is '1020am' instead of '1020 am' ?

Comment: That also wasn't part of the spec. It seems you need to find out what you want first... you can replace the second `\b` with `(?!\d)`, that should suffice to fix *this* immediate problem.

Comment: @TimPietzcker \b or \d ?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? :) (I did mean what I wrote)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with a regular expression.   You will need to write a function to apply some logic to the input string and decide what time to convert it to.  Some of your possible inputs are

- 4
- 12:00 am
- 1200
- 12 am
- 4:40
- 4.40

etc.  This needs to be done by you in a function.

Comment: I agree. Reg ex only works when you are sure of the input type or the Regular expression itself. Here both are variable. So you have to apply logic